# Using DisplayFor with an individual index of a nested property - Lambda Parameter not in scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an `Approval` class, which has a list of `ApprovalDocument` objects.
The `Approvals` class has an `ActiveApprovalDocument` property.

My model has a list of `Approval`s.

I want too show a property of the active approval document:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Approvals[i].ApprovalDocuments[m.Approvals[i].ActiveApprovalDocumentsId.Value].CertificationIssuedDate)%>
```

I realise I could just directly display `Model.Approvals[i]....` but **how can I still use the `DisplayFor` (so I get the automatic formatting etc.)?**

---

The error I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression compiler was unable to evaluate the indexer expression 'm.Approvals.get_Item(value(ASP.areas_approvals_views_approvals_index_aspx+<>c__DisplayClass0).i).ActiveApprovalDocumentsId.Value' because it references the model parameter 'm' which is unavailable. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda Parameter not in scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<% var j = Model.Approvals[i].ActiveApprovalDocumentsId.Value; %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Approvals[i].ApprovalDocuments[j].CertificationIssuedDate) %>
```

Or just use a view model.

Comment: That works great (+1, thanks), but why doesn't my version work?

Comment: Your version doesn't work because strongly typed helpers (those that take a lambda expression as first argument) work only with simple lambda expressions: property accessor and indexer. In your case the indexer access is done based on the value of some complex expression, not just a simple integer value. You could take it as a limitation.